# WP_Query issue inside functions.php & Elementor Pro's 'Query ID' query filter (Posts Widget)

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to get (what I believe should be trivial) thing to work, but somehow I can't get through...

**ISSUE**
I'm trying to - on simple page load - manipulate data in Elementor Pro's 'Posts Widget' that has 'Query ID' filed that gets triggered before results show up. The call successfully 'flies in'. Some 'basic' queries work, but when I want to create 'new WP_Query' all dies with **502 Bat Gateway (in Nginx)**. I'm not getting any useful info in error logs.

- Elementor Pro's Posts Widget is inserted into the basic `Page` in Wordpress
- No other templates are loading (no header/footer/wrapper, nothing)...plain Page, edited with Elementor
- All plugins are disabled (besides El, El Pro and Pods)
- Theme is *Child Hello Theme* (official from Elementor team). Functions.php is clean. Just this piece of code in it.

**CODE** (saved in functions.php file served from Elementor's *Hello Child Theme*)

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/pcp_access', function( $query ) {

    $testQuery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' );
    print_r( testQuery );

} );
```

**ERROR LOG** (xdebug dies flat! This is all that I get...)

```
[26-May-2021 15:43:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 1768 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 22.820869 seconds from start
2021/05/26 15:43:35 [error] 1735#1735: *9 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 172.18.0.6, server: _, request: "GET /test-getting-posts/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "cool-domain-dev.ddev.site"
[26-May-2021 15:43:35] NOTICE: [pool www] child 1771 started
```

**QUESTION**
*Am I missing something in my understanding of how WP_Query works or is there likely something else?*

**MY GUESS**

1. Guys at Elementor likely are triggering their piece of code from `pre_get_posts()` and my '`new WP_Query()`' somehow **isn't supposed to be used at the same time** as the main query? Not sure why that would be.

I'm slowly out of ideas ‍♂️ Any input is welcomed

p.s. Of course I could hit DB directly trough *global* `$wpdb->get_results(SQL_CODE, ARRAY_A)` but still...I'd really want to know why is this failing

Comment: I'm actually wondering the same. Were you ever able to find a fix?

Comment: I think part of the issue is that `pre_get_posts` is a filter on the queries that run, so using `WP_Query` within my `pre_get_posts` filter function is causing me to get maximum function nesting level errors. What I'm not sure about yet is how to get my custom data into the Elementor custom query. But I still need to access a query of data within the filter in order to conditionally handle the inside of my `pre_get_posts`.